# UV tiling. Island is stretched

Tags: uv

There is a tiling problem with one side of a wall on a mesh that I am working on. The island is stretched  for a reason that I do not know why.

[image]

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped the object? Have you edited the mesh since you UV unwrapped it? If the so, you may need to UV unwrap again.

Comment: I haven't edited the mesh since i unwrapped it. This the result of the unwrap by selecting the sharp edges and using them as seams.

Comment: You can try to UV unwrap it manually.